# Binding a click event (B) after an initial click event (A) causes event B to fire immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

http://codepen.io/oliecs/pen/womLPJ

```
var nav = {

    init: function () {
        console.log('nav init');

        $nav = $('nav');
        $navIcon = $('.nav-icon');

        $navIcon.on('click',function(){
            nav.show();
        })
    },

    show: function () {
        console.log('nav show');

        $nav.addClass('active');
        $_DOCUMENT.on('click.navisopen',function(){ //document is a global variable
            nav.close();
        })
    },

    close: function () {
        console.log('nav close');

        $nav.removeClass('active');
        $_DOCUMENT.off('.navisopen');
    }
};
```

I feel the pen describes this better than I can. I want to click the nav-icon to open the nav, then any clicks after this will close the nav. However, the close event is fired instantly after the first click, resulting in the nav opening and closing instantly. I don't know how to make this sequential.

Comment: Is the initial click event still being processed, when you add another event handler to it, which then gets executed after the first event handler completes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

```
    $navIcon.on('click',function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        nav.show();
    })
```

Because the first click is bubbling up the DOM all the way to the document where that event handler is triggered.

Answer (score 2):

Updated js file..Use this code

```
    var ecs= {};
    ecs.common = (function($) {
    var $_DOCUMENT = $(document),
    $_WINDOW = $(window),
    $nav = $('nav'),
    $navIcon = $('.nav-icon');
    var nav = {
        init: function () {
            console.log('nav init');
            $nav = $('nav');
            $navIcon = $('.nav-icon');
            $navIcon.on('click',function(){
                nav.show();
            })
        },
        show: function () {
            console.log('nav show');
            $nav.addClass('active');
            // $_DOCUMENT.on('click.navisopen',function(){
            //     nav.close();
            // })
        },
        close: function () {
            console.log('nav close');
            $nav.removeClass('active');
            $_DOCUMENT.off('.navisopen');
        }
    };
    //--------------------
    //  DOM Ready
    //--------------------
    $(function() {
        nav.init();
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        var container = $(".nav-icon");
        if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            /* if the target of the click isn't the container && nor a descendant of the container */
            $nav.removeClass('active');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I'd rework it to use the `nav.close` in the `mouseup` as it keeps it DRY. Is there any reason to use `mouseup` when `click` works? The two aren't necessarily interchangeible